# IIS Worker Process memory keeps increasing while asp.net run ffmpag process

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ffmpeg

I am running this code every 4 second

```
protected string output = string.Empty;
protected Process process;
protected StreamReader sr;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-an -flv_metadata 1 -analyzeduration 1 -i \"rtmp://localhost/test/testStream live=1\" -s 700*394 -r 5 -vframes 10 -f image2pipe -";
    process.StartInfo.FileName = Page.MapPath("ffmpeg.exe");
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Start();

    sr = process.StandardOutput;
    output = sr.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    if (output.Length > 200)
    {
        process.Close();
        if (process != null)
        {
            process.Dispose();
            if (process != null)
            {
                try { process.Kill(); }
                catch { }
                process = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I using asp.net c# to run a FFmpeg process in order to get image data 
from rtmp stream 
the code is working fine but the problem is 
IIS Worker Process memory keeps increasing.

I tried to use the using statement
and:
Close,
Dispose,
Kill,
process = null
but nothing help

How I can stop this memory from increasing?
Is there a better way to control IIS Worker Process memory
from asp.net c# code?

Comment: This code actually is not use asp.net but windows shell and you run this ffmpeg.exe....

Comment: Are you suggesting that i need to run process of cmd.exe and then in the arguments to operate ffmpg.exe throw the command line?

Comment: Actually what I am say here is that the memory of asp.net is probably increasing for two reasons. One is because the ffmpeg.exe is need to load the huge avi in memory for processing (try to run it alone from command line to see whats happens with memory), or second you have other problems on asp.net. For example when you run this do you allow other pages to be processing or they all wait for that one, do you have make tests ?

Comment: I try to run it alone from the command line and the memory not increasing . after running it goes back down. i run it on my localhost and allow other pages to be processing but on my localhost i run only one page, the test page. so its problem on asp.net but what could it be?